# Disabling Win+Tab in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry, hotkeys

How can I disable the <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> hotkey in Windows 7? I want to do this with the native Windows instruments (regedit?) and don't want to use outside programs like Autohotkey or Winkiller.

I tried to edit the registry: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced`, added new `DisabledHotkeys` key of type `REG_SZ` with a value of `Tab`.

It doesn't work, but <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> is easily disabled with value `M`. Or can <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> not be disabled by editing the registry?

I need this hotkey to use it in Eclipse.

Comment: Well, this registry key and its equivalent group policy setting is used to disable Win + X Key combinations, which are intended for launching the pinned icons on the taskbar. I can't find any other way of disabling hotkeys without AutoHotKey. But one way still exists, but this will turn off all hotkeys. Right click on a blank area of desktop, click on Graphics options > Hot keys then click Disable.

Comment: You can only disable printable keys via the registry. For Win+Tab you need AHK.